# Selenium; Нужно кликнуть по рандомному элементу массива

Tags: java, массивы, selenium

`steps.setInputsArray(driver.findElements(By.className(steps.inputsArrayLocator)));
randomInput = (int) (Math.random() * steps.getInputsArray().size());
(Тут нужно осуществить клик)`

Не могу понять по какому локатору лучше осуществлять клик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
steps.getInputsArray().get(randomInput).click();
```

Всё было до ужаса просто!